# apache freezes without log or error messages

Tags: php, windows, apache

I need to install large sites locally on two developers workstations. The sites are written in php5 with parts in Zend 1.10 and the database is MySQL. The production server runs on windows server 2003 . The sites are already running on windows vista on a development station and on windows 7 on another one.

On two workstations where i have to install (a windows xp and a windows 7), the same strange phenomenon occurs: after a few successfull requests apache freezes and no longer responds to any query. The site does not work until a reboot of Apache that takes quite a long time (> 30 seconds) . There is nothing in Windows Event Viewer or in the apache logs. Handle.exe tells me nothing and even freezes when apache starts to hang. Windows tasks manager shows nothing unusual. I have compared the host file , php.ini , httpd.conf and httpd.vhost.conf with stations that work without finding any difference.

The configuration includes mod_rewrite , mod_proxy , apc , memcached. Apache version is 2.2 and PHP 5.3.x (thread safe). The code is under version control, database and data directories are synchronized.

Not familiar with windows , I'm looking for tools or assumptions to solve this problem .

Comment: Consider editing your post into a more readable format. 'Wall-o-Text' does not make for an easy read.

Answer (score 0):

I provide some information about a temporary solution I applied. I noticed that a fraction of the php code was executed before Apache freezes.

Execution stops within a Zend Class, `Zend_Validate_Ip` in the `setOptions` method. At this time, the file is locked for writing and held by httpd.exe.

I found that this file was slightly different from the original version (Zend 1.11.11) : the `require_once` have been removed. This is an acceptable optimization recommended by the [official documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/performance.classloading.html#performance.classloading.striprequires).

However, restoring the `require_once` in that file, the problem is solved. Apache no longer freezes and everything works. So there must be a problem with class loading but I do not understand exactly what it is.